# How do I continue development of an abandoned GitHub repository (with options for them merging later)?

Tags: git, github

Suppose I fork a repo on GitHub, create a feature branch from `master`, make some changes and submit a pull request. If the original repo is abandoned, the pull request isn't merged (or rejected). I'd like to continue making changes to my fork, with the changes dependent on each other (i.e. I wouldn't want to create a new branch from the original master every time, like I would if I was submitting pull requests to an active original repo). I'd like to do it in such a way that if the original repo ever became active again, they could merge in my changes if they wanted to.

What are the options/best way to do this?

I could just continue to use `master` - make feature branches from that and merge them back into it. How would the original repo update themselves to include my changes if they wanted to later?

Should I create some kind of `master-2` branch and use that as a new master? I suppose if I do that, the original repo could just merge that if they wanted to, so that sounds quite clean, but then I've got `master` and `master-2` branches. While I don't mind personally, is there a better way of doing it? Any suggested naming conventions for the new master?

I'm only thinking of small personal type repo's with no user base to speak of, so this is just about how to manage branches, not a community of users/developers.

Comment: Having a `master-2` (named a bit better) branch is a technically good solution.

Comment: @zerkms: any suggestions for what to call the new master branch? I've tried searching, but haven't found any naming conventions for this kind of scenario

Comment: `pauls-fork` may be. I'd probably choose something with `fork` in it.